# remove duplicate in double left join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I know there are several questions about this already.
But i cant find a answer from them about my case.

I need to produce a report with some data combines from three tables.
There is relations between those tables but some data may not match the related table, so i cant use a inner join.

So I tried with left join. This kinda worked but now I get back to many rows due to the `left join`.

I have set up a test case here -> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/637b1/1

```
CREATE TABLE [xOrder](
[ID] [uniqueidentifier] ROWGUIDCOL  NOT NULL,
[SomeText] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL DEFAULT (''))
GO
CREATE TABLE [Order_Time](
[ID] [uniqueidentifier] ROWGUIDCOL  NOT NULL,
[OrderId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
[SomeText] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL DEFAULT (''),
[TimeTypeId] [int] NOT NULL DEFAULT ((-1)),
[TimeType2Id] [int] NOT NULL DEFAULT ((-1)))
GO
CREATE TABLE [Terms](
[ID] [int] NOT NULL,
[CategoryId] [int] NOT NULL,
[SomeText] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL DEFAULT (''))
GO

Insert into [xOrder] (ID, SomeText) VALUES ('db63ddb9-40d9-4d41-9dfc-5335c400dbd8','aaa')
Insert into [xOrder] (ID, SomeText) VALUES ('ef19af2d-66e9-4de1-a9a2-178b61dfe958','bbb')
Insert into [xOrder] (ID, SomeText) VALUES (newid(),'ccc')
GO
Insert into Order_Time (ID, OrderId, SomeText, TimeTypeId, TimeType2Id) VALUES (newid(),'db63ddb9-40d9-4d41-9dfc-5335c400dbd8', 'time1.1', 1, 1)
Insert into Order_Time (ID, OrderId, SomeText, TimeTypeId, TimeType2Id) VALUES (newid(),'db63ddb9-40d9-4d41-9dfc-5335c400dbd8', 'time1.2', 1, -1)
Insert into Order_Time (ID, OrderId, SomeText, TimeTypeId, TimeType2Id) VALUES (newid(),'db63ddb9-40d9-4d41-9dfc-5335c400dbd8', 'time1.3', -1, -1)
GO
Insert into Order_Time (ID, OrderId, SomeText, TimeTypeId, TimeType2Id) VALUES (newid(),'ef19af2d-66e9-4de1-a9a2-178b61dfe958', 'time2.1', 2, 2)
Insert into Order_Time (ID, OrderId, SomeText, TimeTypeId, TimeType2Id) VALUES (newid(),'ef19af2d-66e9-4de1-a9a2-178b61dfe958', 'time2.2', 2, -1)
Insert into Order_Time (ID, OrderId, SomeText, TimeTypeId, TimeType2Id) VALUES (newid(),'ef19af2d-66e9-4de1-a9a2-178b61dfe958', 'time2.3', -1, -1)
GO
Insert into Terms (ID, CategoryId, SomeText) VALUES (1, 1, 'Term1')
Insert into Terms (ID, CategoryId, SomeText) VALUES (2, 1, 'Term2')
Insert into Terms (ID, CategoryId, SomeText) VALUES (3, 1, 'Term3')
Insert into Terms (ID, CategoryId, SomeText) VALUES (1, 2, 'Category1')
Insert into Terms (ID, CategoryId, SomeText) VALUES (2, 2, 'Category2')
Insert into Terms (ID, CategoryId, SomeText) VALUES (3, 2, 'Category3')
GO
```

And this i the query i have tried.

```
select o.SomeText as OrderText, ot.SomeText as TimeText1, coalesce(t.SomeText, 'NotFound') as TermText, coalesce(tt.SomeText, 'NotFound') as CategoryText from xOrder o
inner join order_time ot on o.id = ot.OrderId
left join terms t on ot.TimeTypeId = t.Id
left join terms tt on (ot.TimeType2Id = t.Id and t.ID = 2)
```

The result i expect is 6 row containing this:

```
----------------------------------------
| aaa | Time1.1 | Term1    | Category1 |
| aaa | Time1.2 | Term1    | NotFound  |
| aaa | Time1.2 | NotFound | NotFound  |
| bbb | Time2.1 | Term2    | Category2 |
| bbb | Time2.2 | Term2    | NotFound  |
| bbb | Time2.2 | NotFound | NotFound  |
----------------------------------------
```

But that isnt happening. So how do i remove the extra rows from the left joins?

Comment: Your second LEFT JOIN has no conditions on that tt table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your join condition

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8beee3c452504473e3c8b926b3f4b11f)**

```
select distinct o.SomeText as OrderText, ot.SomeText as TimeText1,
coalesce(t.SomeText, 'NotFound') as TermText, 
coalesce(tt.SomeText, 'NotFound') as CategoryText
from xOrder o
inner join order_time ot on o.id = ot.OrderId  
left join terms t on ot.TimeTypeId = t.id and  t.CategoryId=1
left join terms tt on ot.TimeTypeId = tt.id and  tt.CategoryId=2
```

OUTPUT:

```
OrderText   TimeText1   TermText    CategoryText
aaa         time1.1     Term1        Category1
aaa         time1.2     Term1        Category1
aaa         time1.3     NotFound     NotFound
bbb         time2.1     Term2        Category2
bbb         time2.2     Term2        Category2
bbb         time2.3     NotFound     NotFound
```

Comment: So simple! Thanks alot! :)

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you want:

```
select o.SomeText as OrderText, ot.SomeText as TimeText1,
       coalesce(t.SomeText, 'NotFound') as TermText,
       coalesce(tt.SomeText, 'NotFound') as CategoryText
from xOrder o inner join
     order_time ot
     on o.id = ot.OrderId left join
     terms t
     on ot.TimeTypeId = t.Id and t.CategoryId = 1 left join
     terms tt
     on ot.TimeType2Id = tt.Id and tt.CategoryId = 2;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=24d6f060bdc2333e7c08d929b6edc50c) is a db<>fiddle.

Your query has some problem with table aliases, which is why you get duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

Try below query:

```
select o.SomeText, ot.sometext,
       coalesce((select someText from terms where id = ot.TimetypeId and categoryid = 1), 'NotFound') TimeType,
       coalesce((select someText from terms where id = ot.Timetype2Id and categoryid = 2), 'NotFound') CategroyId
from xOrder o
join order_time ot on o.id = ot.OrderId
```